# Drawing to HTML5 Canvas via a virtual frame buffer device

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, framebuffer

How would one go about drawing the output of a program running outside the browser onto a canvas? I was thinking along the lines of using a virtual frame buffer, but am unsure of how one would proceed with the process. I figure that there would have to be some intermediate processing or mapping of the pixel data with JavaScript as an intermediary.

Does anyone have any recommendations or insight that they could offer?

Thanks

Comment: What type of output is the external program generating--images, text, vectors?  Depending on the output, canvas might  or might not be a good choice.

Comment: The output would mainly consist of images and small amounts of text.

Comment: Canvas is capable of images using canvas.context.drawImage() and text using canvas.context.fillText(). Canvas is capable of rendering 30-60fps video plus adding a caption to each frame--and fairly simple to do. Here is a blog post on how to catch video and draw into canvas.

Comment: did you mean to post a link?

Comment: Chuckle =) ... yes I did!  Here it is: http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

Comment: maybe communication with websockets with "server" and drawing output data on canvas? :-)

Comment: Just throwing in an idea: Maybe you could make the program output the image as if it were from a webcam, then you should be able to access it (with permission) in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to MarkE's and Philipp's nudging I found what seems to be the beginnings of a suitable solution.

Although it does't involve a framebuffer directly, I found Guacamole an HTML5 remote desktop gateway, http://guac-dev.org/ it only uses Ajax and  HTML5 to render on the desktop of a remote system using vnc or RDP protocols in the browser. Its open source and is a suitable starting point in my view.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is a bit old...

As an alternative to [Guacamole](https://github.com/glyptodon/guacamole-client) (Linux/Apache/Java), you may have a look to [Myrtille](https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille), (Windows/IIS/C#). It works for both HTML4 (using divs and xhr) and HTML5 (using canvas and websockets).

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 canvas is not designed to do that. Its designed to read image (or video) data from the web and display it, either as normal http download or as xmlHttpRequest. When you need to get image data generated by an external application into the javascript engine of the web browser, you need to expose that image data as a webservice.